# Multiple process BackgroundWorker with classes

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker, background-process

I make an application with WPF. I use a method in another class that goes through all the images in the folder from the MainForm class. I want the `ProgressBar` to be updated, so I send a request to this class to check for changes in the number of images processed. But it does not even process images. I use the `BackgroundWorker` class to do this. The MainForm code below:

```
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ImageProcessing detector;
        BackgroundWorker worker;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PathTextBox.Text != "")
            {
                detector = new ImageProcessing(isFolder, PathTextBox.Text);
                worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        private void MainForm_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.DoWork += Worker_CheckChangingProcessedImages;
            worker.DoWork += Worker_RunProcessingImages;
            worker.ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged;
        }

        private void Worker_RunProcessingImages(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            detector.DetectTextOnImage();
        }

        private void Worker_CheckChangingProcessedImages(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (detector.ReturnNumberProcessedImages() <= Progress.Maximum)
                (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(detector.ReturnNumberProcessedImages());
        }

        private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int numberProcessed = detector.ReturnNumberProcessedImages();
            Progress.Value = numberProcessed;

            if (numberProcessed == 0) LogTextBox.Text = "Start processing";
            else if ((numberProcessed == 1) && (Progress.Maximum == 1))
                LogTextBox.Text += "\n1 image is processed";
            else if (numberProcessed % 10 == 0)
                LogTextBox.Text += $"\n{numberProcessed} images are processed";

            if (numberProcessed == Progress.Maximum)
                LogTextBox.Text += "\nEverything is processed";
        }
    }
```

The ImageProcessing class has a field with the number of processed images. The `DetectTextOnImage()` method has a foreach loop. The code below:

```
private int numberProcessedImages = 0;

public void DetectTextOnImage()
{
    foreach (String imageFileName in Directory.GetFiles(path))
    {
        // do something
        numberProcessedImages++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Subscribe to the `DoWork` event just once. Pass the Path of the images to the BackGrounWorker (`RunworkerAsync([object])`, you'll find it in `DoWorkEventArgs.Argument`) -- Declare and initialize the `ImageProcessing` object in the `DoWork` handler. -- When you pass the current value to `.ReportProgress()`, you don't have to read it again (`int numberProcessed = detector.ReturnNumberProcessedImages();`), instead get the computed value from `ProgressChangedEventArgs.UserState`. -- Not clear how you determined the maximum value of the Progressbar.

Comment: All in all, you could instead run a Task and use a [Progress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) delegate to report back to UI Thread the progress, which simplifies everything quite a bit.

Comment: Instead of a `BackgroundWorker` consider using `async` `await`